# Why zuul proxy dont relay oauth2 token?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, netflix-zuul

I have gateway backed zuul proxy, and service to proxying.
When I try to request to service via gateway I recieve 401. Zuul dont relay token.

Zuul and OAuth2 config

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
@EnableZuulProxy
public class LogInConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public OAuth2RestOperations restOperations(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource, OAuth2ClientContext context){
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource, context);
    }

}
```

My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-ribbon'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-core'
    implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api'
    implementation group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-impl', version: '2.3.0.1'
    implementation group: 'com.sun.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-core', version: '2.3.0.1'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}
```

As you see spring-cloud-starter-security added.

Comment: Have you tried using forwarding headers?

Comment: I tried to implement ZuulFilter thats put Authorization Header at request to origin. But header not added. Somthing block that header to add. Then I set zuul.ignoreSecurityHeaders=false. Problem still exists.